# Is pg_test_fsync contrib module in postgresql 9.2 deprecated?

Tags: postgresql, psql, fsync

I have installed postgresql 9.2.4 on my machine with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. Based on this documentation page (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgtestfsync.html), it seems *pg_test_fsync* contrib module is part of postgresql 9.2.4 . But when I checked *pg_available_extensions* system view and also the following location on my system */usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension*, I could not find this module. It seems to be missing even in the contrib documentation here (http://packages.debian.org/experimental/postgresql-contrib-9.2).

Am I missing something? Could anyone guide me on how can I test 'pg_test_fsync' on postgresql 9.2.4 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not all contrib modules are extensions. `pg_test_fsync` is not deprecated; rather the opposite, it's a very important and heavily used tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual page you link to is for a command-line tool, not a function which runs inside the database itself, so will not show up when interrogating system views for available extensions.

Although the [Debian package description](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/postgresql-contrib-9.2) doesn't mention it, the [list of files included](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/amd64/postgresql-contrib-9.2/filelist) does. The list includes both `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_test_fsync` and `/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/pg_test_fsync.1.gz`, so once that package is installed, you should be able to type `man pg_test_fsync` to confirm the options supported.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to locate the pg_test_fsync in the above mentioned location and the tests are running fine.